# How to enter Ubuntu after installing it on Windows 10

Tags: boot, windows-10

Windows 10 kept asking for activation and I had no product key, and I installed **Ubuntu 20.04.3 L**
But after installation, I couldn't enter Ubuntu but keep entering Windows.
This was my first time installing Ubuntu so I may have made some mistakes, maybe in creating free spaces while installation, I don't know.
Now I see Ubuntu in *F disk* (I had no such disk before). What should I do to enter Ubuntu and move my files, documents and other things to the system and delete Windows?
Thanks for your help! I appreciate it!

Comment: Please be clear what did you install?

Comment: *What should I do to enter Ubuntu and move my files, documents and other things to the system and delete Windows?* This is the wrong question. First you do your backups somewhere else (external drive, cloud, etc.) *then* you install Ubuntu with the option to "erase and install" *if* your goal is to have Ubuntu only.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to AU.

It's worth pointing out that, aside from the annoying reminders to activate, there are relatively few disadvantages to running Windows that isn't activated - I don't think you can customise the desktop background for example, but it does work otherwise.

If you do want to switch to Ubuntu -

First thing to do - if you're new to Ubuntu - is check that you're happy using it. You've presumably created an installation USB already. Shut down your computer, put the USB in and restart. You may need to set the Bios to use USB as the first boot priority. Then select 'Try Ubunutu' which lets you use a fully functional version of Ubuntu running from your USB stick. Play around with it, check you are happy with how it works as it is very different to Windows.

If you are happy to use it, the next step is to copy all the files you want to keep from your Windows setup to an external drive. You can either do that from Windows - just drop the files onto a spare USB drive - or do it from the live Ubuntu USB session you've started. Either way, ensure you have backed up absolutely everything you want to keep. I would not rely on backing it up to an internal drive on your computer, even if you have more than one hard drive in there. Ideally, don't use the drive you have the live session (Ubuntu installation media) on.

Once you've got secure backups of everything you need, install Ubuntu and erase Windows - the installer gives you that option. Then copy the files you backed up into Documents or wherever you want to store them.

You might also want to prepare some data before you delete Windows so the downtime when you don't have a fully functional computer is shorter - eg Wifi access codes, internet favourites / bookmarks, printer IP addresses if networked, music playlists, create a list of software you will want to install in Ubuntu and what the equivalent software is for proprietary Windows programs.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I have already installed Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS and before installation I saved my necessary files in cloud. So, therefore while installation I deleted my previous Windows system and everything and then installed but after installation, my laptop asked to restart the computer and I did  and when I was restarting the computer, it asked to remove the USB and press enter. After doing that, unfortunately I couldn't enter my laptop. It kept turning off and when I inter the USB, it worked but also when I restarted again, it showed SQUASHFS Error.

Comment: Sorry you’re having problems. I think you should post a new question with all the details - including your hardware, whether you checked your usb media after writing the Ubuntu iso, and full details of the error messages you’re getting. I suspect your best option is to start again with a fresh installation, with a usb iso that definitely works, but do post the question with full details and someone will try to help you.